# Get the sum of the count and do the subtract of the count python

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, split, count

I want to get the sum of counts of Key word minus sum of the opposite word and then return the sentences. Here is what I have:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Test.xlsx')
df.drop_duplicates(['Content'],inplace=True)
a = df['Content'].str.lower()
searchfor =['heating','lagging',... and 100+words]
opposite = ['no heating','no lagging',...and 100+words]
b = a[a.str.contains(searchfor)]
c = a[a.str.contains(opposite)]
```

for example in Content, I have sentences ['The phone is heating but not lagging', 'The phone is not heating and not lagging'...]
First sentence contains the 2 words in searchfor and 1 word in opposite. Second sentence contains 2 words from searchfor and 2 words from opposite. What I want to do is count the sum of number of words in both searchfor and opposite. Then (sum of keywords in searchfor minus sum of keywords in opposite. If is zero, return the sentences.

Here is what I tried but it is does not work

```
d = c.str.split()
def check_it(sentences):
   find_words = []
   for word in searchfor:
        if word in sentences:
            find_words.append(d.count(word))
   return sentences
d = d.apply(lambda x:check_it(x))
```

and do one more def check it. It wont works and gives me error.

I will be thankful if someone could help

Comment: Could you provide the error message?

Comment: it says 'Level Lagging must be same as name(None)'. But what I am thinking is maybe my def check it method is run

Comment: What I actually want is do the sum of the count the key words in searchfor and opposite, then do the subtraction

Answer (score 2):

[Using Python 3, requires Pandas]

It would be good to see a sample of your actual data, however, I am assuming your dataframe would have a sample as shown below (Please correct me if this is not the case):

```
+-----+----------------------------------------+
|index|content                                 |
+-----+----------------------------------------+
|0    |the phone is heating but not lagging    |
|1    |the phone is not heating and not lagging|
+-----+----------------------------------------+
```

We now create a function to be used as a lambda as follows:

```
def get_difference_of_keywords(content_string, searchfor, opposite):
    searchfor_matches = len([keyword for keyword in searchfor if keyword in content_string])
    opposite_matches = len([keyword for keyword in opposite if keyword in content_string])
    difference = searchfor_matches - opposite_matches
    if not difference == 0:
        return str(difference)
    return content_string
```

This uses python's list comprehension to grab the number of matches of 'searchfor' and 'opposite' then returns the difference, if the difference is not zero, or the original input sentence if the difference is equal to zero.

Note: I have converted the returned number from a difference above zero to a string to make sure you don't have mixed data types in the new columns. This is optional and up to you.

We then apply the above:

```
df['get_difference_result'] = df.apply(
    lambda row: get_difference_of_keywords(row['content'], searchfor, opposite),
    axis=1
)
```

Which will result in the following:

```
+-----+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|index|content                                 |get_difference_result                   
|
+-----+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|0    |the phone is heating but not lagging    |1                                       |
|1    |the phone is not heating and not lagging|the phone is not heating and not lagging|
+-----+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help! If this resolved your problem, would you mind accepting my answer?